# problem in Configure Apache to use mod_jk

Tags: java, apache, mod-jk, tomcat7

I simply copy "ant" and "tomcat" into `/usr/local/`
then add this lines to `/etc/profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
export JRE_HOME=/usr/java/latest/jre
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

---

```
#ant -version return:
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
```

---

Apache web server works well, http://localhost/ is ok

---

in http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html#s7 says that `startup.sh` with option `jkconf` will generate a file in:

```
Include TOMCAT_HOME/conf/auto/mod_jk.conf
```

but its not there

---

I run this command:

```
[root@localhost tomcat]# sh startup.sh -jkconf
```

Comment: Looking at the Tomcat 3.3 manual is unlikely to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I cant understand why, but after reboot everything works great